# NodeJS: Use Promises in Loop with Q

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a problem with promises in a loop. The whole promise thing is completely new to me, so I try to learn it with very simple examples.

In my example, I have 2 text files on a server and I want to save the content of the text files into an array.

It works with a setTimeout, but this is not the solution that I want. Here is the example wit setTimeout

```
var http = require('http'),
        Q = require('q');

var urls = ["http://localhost:8000/1.txt", "http://localhost:8000/2.txt"]
var txts = [];

function getData(url) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        var data = "";
        res.on('data',function(chunk){
            data+=chunk;
        });
        res.on('end',function(){
            txts.push(data);
        });

    }).on('error',function(e){
        console.log("Error Request: "+e.message);
    })
}

function getTxts() {

    for(a in urls) {
        var url = urls[a];
        getData(url);
    }

  // is not working
  console.log(txts);
  // is working
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(txts);
  }, 1000)
}

getTxts();
```

I now tried doing it with Q, but I am stuck at some point. There is some point where I am going into the wrong direction, but I can't see where it is.

```
var http = require('http'),
        Q = require('q');

var urls = ["http://localhost:8000/1.txt", "http://localhost:8000/2.txt"]
var txts = [];

function getData(url) {
  return Q.promise(function(respond,reject){
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        var data = "";
        res.on('data',function(chunk){
            data+=chunk;
        });
        res.on('end',function(){
            txts.push(data);
        });

    }).on('error',function(e){
        console.log("Error Request: "+e.message);
    })
  });
}

function getTxts() {

  var promises = [];
    for(a in urls) {
        var url = urls[a];
        var promise = getData(url);
    promises.push(promise);
    }

  return promises;
}

function start() {
  Q.fcall(function() {
    getTxts();
  }).then(function() {
    console.log(txts);
  })
}

start();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use just regular promises for this

```
var http = require('http');
var urls = ["http://localhost:8000/1.txt", "http://localhost:8000/2.txt"]

function getData(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        http.get(url, function(res) {
            var data = "";
            res.on('data',function(chunk){
                data+=chunk;
            });
            res.on('end',function(){
                resolve(data);
            });

        }).on('error',function(err){
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

function getTxts() {
    return Promise.all(
        urls.map(function(url) {
            return getData(url);
        })
    );
}

getTxts().then(function(texts) {
    // "texts" is an array of the returned data
}).catch(function(err) {
    // epic fail
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you are not resolving or rejecting the promise you created in the getData function

```
function getData(url) {
  return Q.promise(function(resolve,reject){
    http.get(url, function(res) {
      var data = "";
      res.on('data',function(chunk){
        data+=chunk;
      });
      res.on('end',function(){
        txts.push(data);
        resolve(); // resolve the promise when done
      });

   }).on('error',function(e){
    console.log("Error Request: "+e.message);
    reject(); // reject the promise if there is an error
 })
```

});
}

Comment: You're right, I was overseeing this. But that's not it, there is something else the Q library requires, what my application does not fulfill.

Comment: Got it! getTxts() needs a return Q.all(promises) and start() calls getTxts().then(function() { /* ... */ }); Thanks for your help!